# DatabaseDesign for a Traveller

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently having problems designing a database. I'm building a small car sharing plattform and im quite unsure how to store 'sharing offers'.

I have people travelling from **A** to **D** (via **B**, **C**)
A → B → C → D
And i've ppl travelling from **C** to **D**.

I thought about splitting the first trip into subtrips (A→B, B→C, C→D). With a "join" on **B** i could find connections from **A** → **C**. But with more intermediate steps, this would become quite slowly (I assume), keep in mind that you shouldn't change the driver/car during one ride.

I read something about 'nested sets', to build up a tree. But I'm not sure if this approach would fit for my problem, as i don't have a root (and i've no clue how to traverse that tree in sql). At the moment i dont know wherelse to start. If you confirm the use of nested sets, i'll dive into that.
But I appreciate any other ideas or suggestion

ps. this is my first post, i hope i got everything right :)

Answer (score 2):

How about one row per stop during a trip, including the order number of the stop? Like this:

```
trip | stop | place
-----+------+------
   1 |    1 |    A
   1 |    2 |    B
   1 |    3 |    C
   1 |    4 |    D
```

That way you can easily find trips that go e.g. from A to C:

```
SELECT t.trip
FROM trips t
JOIN trips s ON (
    t.trip = s.trip AND
    t.place = "A" AND
    s.place = "C" AND
    t.stop < s.stop
);
```

This way the query will always be the same, regardless of subtrips.

Comment: I had the exact same thought so I nix'd my post.

Comment: Ah, quite obvious but a nice solution. Thanks for reading and taking the time to think this through. appreciate both efforts. thanks. cheers